# Synchronization issue with ALAssetsLibrary assetForURL method

Tags: ios, objective-c, synchronization, alassetslibrary

I am having some synchronization issue with loading asset from `ALAssetsLibrary`.

Actually, what I am trying is to load some pictures from camera roll whose urls are given by some database query. Now after obtaining urls from database I use those urls to load the pictures using  `assetForURL` method of `ALAssetsLibrary` and after the picture is loaded I display the picture to some view. So I call the method inside a loop that is executed every time the query result-set returns a record. And everything works fine till now. Below is a sample code to demonstrate the process:

```
ALAssetsLibrary* library = [ALAssetsLibrary new];
//dispatch_group_t queueGroup = dispatch_group_create();
while ([rs next]) {
    //some data load up

    //load thumbnails of available images
    [library assetForURL:url resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
        UIImage* img = [[UIImage imageWithCGImage:asset.aspectRatioThumbnail] retain];

        //dispatch_group_async(queueGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //create views and add to container view
            CGFloat left = (8.0f + dimension) * i + 8.0f;
            CGRect rect = CGRectMake(left, 8.0f, dimension, dimension);
            TileView* tileView = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TileView" owner:nil options:nil][0];
            [tileView setFrame:rect];
            tileView.tag = i;
            tileView.active = NO;
            [self.thumbnailContainer addSubview:tileView];

                            //display image in tileView, etc.

                            //.............
            if (img) {
                [img release];
            }
            NSLog(@"block %d: %d",i,[self.thumbnailContainer.subviews count]);
            //});
    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"failed to load image");
    }];

    i++;
}

NSLog(@"outside block %d",[self.thumbnailContainer.subviews count]);
[library release];
```

In my code `self.thumbnailContainer` is a UIScrollView and inside that I add my custom views to display the thumbnail images and it works as expected.

The real dilemma comes when I try to select the very last view added to `self.thumbnailContainer`. I cant find any way to determine when all the asynchronous blocks of `assetForURL` methods completed so that `self.thumbnailContainer` actually contains some subviews. So if I log count of subviews of `self.thumbnailContainer` just after the loop completes it shows 0. And after that I find all the block codes get executed increasing count of subviews. It is very expected behavior but contradicts my requirements. I have tried `dispatch_group_` and `dispatch_wait` methods from GCD but without any success.

Can anyone please suggest a workaround or an alternative coding pattern to overcome the situation. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might utilize a dispatch group, as you likely had in mind:

```
- (void) loadViewsWithCompletion:(completion_t)completionHandler {
    ALAssetsLibrary* library = [ALAssetsLibrary new];
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
    while ([rs next]) {
        dispatch_group_enter(group);
        [library assetForURL:url resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
            UIImage* img = [[UIImage imageWithCGImage:asset.aspectRatioThumbnail] retain];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                //create views and add to container view
                ...

                dispatch_group_leave(group);
            });
        } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"failed to load image");
            dispatch_group_leave(group);
        }];

        i++;
    }
    [library release];
    if (completionHandler) {
        dispatch_group_notify(group, ^{
            completionHandler(someResult);
        });
    }
    ...  release dispatch group if not ARC
}
```

The code *might* have a potential issue though:

Since you asynchronously load images, they may be loaded all in parallel. This *might* consume a lot of system resources. If this is the case, which depends on the implementation of the asset loader method `assetForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock:`, you need to *serialize* your loop.

Note: Method `assetForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock:` *may* already ensure that access to the asset library is serialized. If the execution context of the completion block is also a serial queue, `[UIImage imageWithCGImage:asset.aspectRatioThumbnail]` will be executed in serial. In this case, your loop just enqueues a number of *tasks* - but processes only one image at a time and you are safe.

Otherwise, if method `assetForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock:` runs in parallel, and/or the block executes an a concurrent queue - images might be loaded and processed in parallel. This *can* be a bad thing if those images are large.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The `dispatch_group_enter`/`dispatch_group_leave` pair worked like a charm for my app. According to Apple,these pair explicitly marks a block to enter/exit a group and that is something I was originally looking for. Also, I found that `resultBlock` of `assetForURL` method are always invoked on the main queue and thus I don't think I need to worry about parallelism, as main queue itself is serial by nature and also I don't need to invoke another block in the main queue to add my views with `dispatch_async`/`dispatch_group_async`, as they are already in the main queue.Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways you can fix this issue. They are

1.**NSLock**. Specifically **NSConditionLock**. Basically you create a lock with the condition “pending tasks”. Then in the completion and error blocks of assetForURL, you unlock it with the “all complete” condition. With this in place, after you call assetForURL, simply call lockWhenCondition using your “all complete” identifier, and you’re done (it will wait until the blocks set that condition)!

[Check this for more detials](http://omegadelta.net/2011/05/10/how-to-wait-for-ios-methods-with-completion-blocks-to-finish/)

2.Manually track the count in `resultBlock` & `failureBlock`

**Note:**

I have mentioned few important things regarding the performance of ALAsset libraries [in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20689538/alassetslibrary-image-twisted/20701897#20701897).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I defer with one proposition from your answer that `assetForURL` blocks work on a separate thread. In my own app I have found that these blocks work on the main thread itself, however, those are queued to the main queue asynchronously, that is, when an asset is successfully loaded, the `resultBlock` is queued itself in the main queue. Asset loading process still works on some different thread by itself. I'll try to work on your `NSConditionLock` suggestion and would get back. Thanks again.

Comment: however use dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() and feel the diffrence in ui part.